# Class not Found exception for saxon parser implementation

Tags: java, xslt-2.0, saxon, transformer-model

I am using "Saxon-HE 9.6.0-4" to convert xml data to HTML.
I am getting the following error. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl

[javax.xml.transform.Source xmlSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(results.getDirectory()
                + "\results.xml");
        javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xsltFile);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

```
    javax.xml.transform.Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw);
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
    javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xmlSource);

    trans.transform(xsltSource, result);]
```

Can anybody please help me out with this issue

Comment: Make sure Saxon is on the class path when you run your Java code.

Comment: I have a pom entry and it is a maven project. I have a runtime folder created under my plugin which includes all the jar files. during runtime these jars should be called. I have a java class path to maven repository where Saxon files are downloaded. When you say Saxon should be on JAVA class path you want me to set it in system environment ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm using Maven to get the library.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

has only one possible meaning: the Saxon JAR file is not on your classpath.

Comment: I have xml and xslt file I need to convert xml file to html. using Saxson-HE 9. can you just provide me sample code?

Comment: It's not a code problem, it's a configuration problem. Without a thorough understanding of the environment in which you are running the application, I can't tell you how to fix the configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example below 
**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <books dept="physics">
        <book id="PHY00001" category="Atomic">
            <name>Concepts of Physics</name>
            <author>H.C.Verma</author>
            <isbn>8177091875</isbn>
            <price>15</price>
            <publisher>Tata</publisher>
        </book>
        <book id="PHY00002" category="Natural">
            <name>Handbook of Physics</name>
            <author>Nipendra Bhatnagar</author>
            <isbn>8177091876</isbn>
            <price>20</price>
            <publisher>Wiley</publisher>
        </book>
        <book id="PHY00003" category="Natural">
            <name>Handbook of Physics II</name>
            <author>Nipendra Bhatnagar</author>
            <isbn>8177091886</isbn>
            <price>25</price>
            <publisher>Wiley Publ.</publisher>
        </book>
    </books>
    <books dept="chemistry">
        <book id="CHE00001" category="Organic">
            <name>Chemistry Formulae And Definitions</name>
            <author>Ramanand Thakur</author>
            <isbn>8177091878</isbn>
            <price>20</price>
            <publisher>ChemWorld</publisher>
        </book>
        <book id="CHE00002" category="Inorganic">
            <name>Handbook of Chemistry</name>
            <author>Hansraj Modi</author>
            <isbn>8177091879</isbn>
            <price>35</price>
            <publisher>BetaBooks</publisher>
        </book>
        <book id="CHE00003" category="Inorganic">
            <name>Handbook of Chemistry II</name>
            <author>Hansraj Modi</author>
            <isbn>8177091889</isbn>
            <price>38</price>
            <publisher>Beta Marketing</publisher>
        </book>
    </books>
</library>
```

**xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Books List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="library/books/book">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="price" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**MainApp.java**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
        try {
            transform("library.xml", "library.xsl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void transform(String xml, String xsl)
            throws TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException {
        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsl)));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xml)), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
}
```

**Ouptut**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Books List</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Concepts of Physics</td>
            <td>15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Handbook of Physics</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Handbook of Physics II</td>
            <td>25</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Chemistry Formulae And Definitions</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Handbook of Chemistry</td>
            <td>35</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Handbook of Chemistry II</td>
            <td>38</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```